# Using qtmotifextension with QT5

Tags: linux, qt, x11, qt5, motif

Currently I'm using `qtmotifextension` to connect QT world with old Motif UI on X11 Linux station.

I'm trying to update towards QT5 but `X11processEvent` from `QApplication` has been removed.
Is there an updated qtmotifextension from old qt-solutions available or is there any way to have `X11processEvent` from QT5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that qtmotifextension is no more maintained... You have to stick to QT4 or re-implement this extension....